# Finding the probability of sum of independent random variables given their Moment Generating Functions

Tags: probability, independence, moment-generating-function

> Let $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ be independent random variables with respective moment generating functions as $$M_{X_{1}}(t) = (\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4}e^t)^3 \ , \  M_{X_{2}}(t)  = e^{2(e^{t}-1)}$$ ,  $$where-\infty < t < \infty$$. 
> Then the value of $P(X_{1} + X_{2} = 0)$ is:

I am aware that the $MGF$ of the sum of 2 random variables is the product of its respective $MGFs$
Hence $$M_{X_{1}+X_{2}}(t) = M_{X_{1}}(t) * M_{X_{2}}(t)$$

How do I procced from here?

**EDIT** : As mentioned by **@StubbornAtom**, I identified the independent variables as following Binomial and Poisson Distribution respectively.

As $X_{1}+X_{2} = 0$ only if $X_{1} = -X_{2}$ or both the variables are equal to $0$. But since both variables cannot take negative values I multiplied the respective $p.m.f$ with value $0$ and got the following:

$$P(X_{1} + X_{2} = 0) = \frac{27}{64}e^{-2}$$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: You only need to identify the distributions of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom The first variable follows binomial distribution and the second is poisson distribution. But How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Your answer seems correct to me.